# Onchange Event for Text Area

Tags: javascript, events, textarea, onchange

I have been trying to use and onchange event on a text area however nothing has been working. the normal change() or onChange() functions do nothing at all.

I have Tried things like

```
$('#areaName').on('input', function(){})
$('#areaName').bind('input', function(){})
```

I have tried eveything solution i have found online to no avail.

I just need the piece of code to trigger a function when the text in the text area has been modified in anyway.

Comment: How about `keypress` event?

Answer (score 2):

The below code working as expected, Tested in Firefox

```
   $(function ()
    {
        $('#areaName').change(function () {
            alert($('#areaName').val());
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me in Firefox:

```
 <textarea oninput="alert('input detected')";>initial input text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use keyboard Events, [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/bqxhCUMRXrIPLxsFdKdL?p=info):

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#area").on("keypress",function(){
    alert("hello")
  })

})
```

If you use **jqueryui** you can capture **resize** event as:

```
 $("#area").resizable({
    resize: function() {
        alert("hello2")
    }
 });
```

Comment: that's jquery, not javascript

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.0/js/select2.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <style>

    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

     <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="textArea">

     </textarea>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#textArea').bind('input propertychange', function() {
          console.log(this.value);
        });
      });
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```